# How to have multiple values per row

Tags: sqlite, perl

I've set up a database with sqlite using perl and I'm trying to figure out how to add multiple values on each row.

I've been trying to change my INSERT INTO statement but have had no success.

```perl
#Here I create the database.
$dbh->do("
    CREATE TABLE probes(
        source CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
        port CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(source,port))")
#This is my prepare statement that I think needs to be changed.
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO probes (source, port) VALUES(?,?)");
```

For example I have a log file that was taken from a scan done, I have a source IP and port number. I want the database to show

```
Source:   Port:
127.0.0.1 5678 5839 5938
```

Instead of it showing like this:

```
Source:   Port:
127.0.0.1 5678
127.0.0.1 5839
127.0.0.1 5938
```

Answer (score 2):

You store one row per scan like you are now, and use grouping and aggregation to get one row per source IP when you're ready to display the data. Something like:

```
SELECT source, group_concat(port, ' ') AS ports
FROM probes
GROUP BY source;
```

[db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=98d0db2ad3d4ecf80a0b6b5e9d5bcd17)

Comment: So I should send an sql execution after everything is already in the DB? Like:
```perl
$dbh->do("SELECT source, group_concat(port, ' ') AS ports
  FROM probes
  GROUP BY source");
```

Comment: @KopLop You wouldn't use `do()` here because you want the results of the query. `selectall_arrayref()` or a `prepare()`, `execute()`, and loop over `fetchrow_array()` sequence or the like. See the DBI documentation for details.